# Spring boot Kafka integration test: Consumer always returns 0 records

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test

For the following test I am always getting the error:

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:  expected: 10 but was : 0

*What exactly I am trying to verify in scope of the test*:

I am trying to send 10 messages to Kafka and after that immediately I am trying to read those messages from Kafka, but for some unknown reason `KafkaConsumer` returns 0 records, and I am struggling to understand why Consumer can't read messages that were sent earlier?

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = TestKafkaContextInitializer.class)
@Slf4j
public class KafkaFlowVerificationITest {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private final String kafkaTopic = "test.topic";

    @Test
    void testKafkaFlow() {
        IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .forEach(e -> {
                    try {
                        kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, UUID.randomUUID().toString()).get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

        checkKafkaForMessage();

    }

    private void checkKafkaForMessage() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);


        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "acme");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        consumer.subscribe(List.of(kafkaTopic));
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ZERO);

        Assertions.assertThat(records.count()).isEqualTo(10);
    }
}
```

and **TestKafkaContextInitializer**:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.test.util.TestPropertyValues;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@Slf4j
public class TestKafkaContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    private final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer =
            new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3"));

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        kafkaContainer.start();
        var values = TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=" + kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers(),
                "spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=" + kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers()
        );
        values.applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt `Duration.ZERO` is what you want since you do want to poll some records

Comment: I have changed value to Duration.ofSeconds(10), and based on logs the issue was identified, for some reason kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers() contains outdated value, not actual value that was initialized in TestKafkaContextInitializer class.

Comment: What do you mean, outdated? `kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers()` should work fine. Also, you really only need to set `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`, not producer and consumer individually

Comment: correct, I set `bootstrap-servers` property separately for `consumer` and `producer`, but in the test I use `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property, it was my mistake.

Comment: Can you just clarify that as an answer to your question and close it? It took me some time to figure out that you use the property in the test which you don't set in the initializer...

Comment: @ArtemBilan, didn't get your point, could you please rephrase your advice?

Comment: My point is that this question needs to have an answer and you really can add answer to your own question. This way the rest of community will benefit from your experience: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is:

I set `TestContainer` `Kafka` bootstrap server url for the following properties:

`spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers`

`spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers`

but in the test I use:
`spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property, that why Consumer made attempt connect to `localhost:9092` default URL instead of URL provided by `TestContainer`.